# Python _ Create multiple dataframe by loop

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, dataframe

I am trying to create multiple dataframes from the existing dictionaries. But after the loop finishes, the dataframes are not saved/made.

```
L1 = ['A','B','C',]
D1 = {'A':[1,2,3],'B':[4,5,6],'C':[7,8,9]}
D2 = {'A':['aa','bb','cc'],'B':['dd','ee','ff'],'C':['gg','hh','ii']}
D3 = {'A':['100','101','102'],'B':['103','104','105'],'C':['106','107','108']}
for each in L1:
    each = pd.DataFrame({(each+'1'):D1[each],(each+'2'):D2[each]},index=D3[each])
print (A)
```

Error message

```
NameError: name 'A' is not defined
```

I know the dataframe is once created since if I print/show the dataframe within the loop then it's ok.

But I want all dataframes to be saved so I can use later.
Appreciate the help!

Comment: You're trying to print something that isn't defined (`A`).  Are you perhaps trying to print something else?

Comment: well you are just reassigning the variable `each`. For the three iteration of your code, `each` will first be 'A', then pd.DF, then 'B', and so on

Comment: yeah, I thought each iteration is gonna create a new dataframe and it will be saved. Then what is the good way to achieve it?